Proving the $\partial E \subset E$ given set $E$ is closed
Let $E$ be a subset of a metric space $(X,d)$. Prove the following:

$E$ is   closed  $\iff$ $\partial E \subset E$

The following is my attempt at this question I noticed the use of the double-headed arrow and I am guessing that I am required to show it in both directions.
Definitions:
$\partial E =$ boundary of $E$,
$\overline E =$ closure of $E$, $E^\circ =$ interior of $E$
Case 1: Given $ \partial E  \subset  E$, $ \overline E  = \partial E \cup E^\circ$. Let $p\in\overline E$. Then $p\in\partial E$ or $p\in E^\circ$. So, $p\in\partial E\subseteq E$ and $p\in E^\circ\subseteq E$. Thus,$\overline E\subseteq E$.
Case 2: $E$ is closed. Then, $E = \overline E=E \cup E^\circ $ Since $\overline E = \partial E  \cup E^\circ $, we get $\partial E \subset \overline E = E$.
I am hoping for any guidance as it relates to my solution.

You should share the definitions you are using. Different books/authors/teachers give different definitions (which later are proven to be equivalent).

You have a typo, you probably didn't mean to write $\overline{A}$.

@jjagmath let me add the definitions

And you're using MathJax incorrectly. Use a single MathJax expression for each mathematical expression. Instead of p $\in$ $\partial E$ $\subseteq E$  you should write $p \in \partial E \subseteq E$.

You might be using the following definition of boundary:
$$\partial E = \overline{E} -E^{\circ}.$$
This means, boundary is a subset of $\overline{E}$. If $E$ is closed, then $E=\overline{E}$. Thus in this case,
$$\partial E \subset E.$$

This looks correct to me.

@Yathi ty for the help and guidance.

@ultralegend5385 ty as well.

For Case 1, you could also have used that $\partial E = \overline{E} \cap \overline{X\setminus E}$.

You didn't add the definitions. You explained the notation but didn't define "closure", "interior" and "boundary". Take for example, the closure of a set $X$. It can be defined as "the intersection of all the closed sets containing $X$" or as "the union of the boundary and the interior of $X$".
